# how external dll reference occurs in linux

Tags: linux, dll

I'm runing an application that uses a library that I created.
This sample application is generated through a make file that builds the application as

```
LIBNAME=/usr/local/App/lib/libMYLIB.so
```

> $(CC) -o sample sample.o $(LIBNAME)

I'm able to run the application without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Is that expected?
Does using full path in LIBNAME has something to do with it?
ldd sample returns (among other entries)

```
/usr/local/App/lib/libMYLIB.so (0x00002aaaaaaad000)
```

What changes do I need to do so that without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable my application shouldn't work. Using -lMyLIB with cc help?

Thanks.

Comment: With regards to being able to execute the application without setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it's most likely that path to libMYLIB.so is in the /etc/ld.so.conf (or it's various loaded child-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L/usr/local/App/lib/ -lMYLIB` is what you are after.

It might be the case that linking with the full library name sets an "rpath", which is basically a sort of an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that is embedded in the executable. You can check the current value of the rpath (if any) using `chrpath <executable>`.

Comment: it doesn't set the RPATH by default

Comment: He probably needs the -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/App/lib link option to get this to work without having the library in the shared object cache